# can we push images to browser cache using javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, browser-cache

We have a print functionality in our application where we are printing images in the browser. We are dynamically forming the HTML div with all the image sources [image source is from the webservice url]

When we trigger 'Windows.Print()' , only the first image is always available in print preview (chrome) and remaining images are displayed blank.

If i trigger the print event for the second time, all the images are getting printed without any issue because all the images are cached by that time.

Please let me know how to push all my images in cache before printing. I need to do this in javascript. Dont want to make any html change.

**I am using backbone.js and creating a model view with the images. Then Binding the view in HTML. Then i ma using for printing. This works fine in IE and Safari. but not in chrome, it shows print preview screen and always trying to load all the images from browser cache. But i will not be having those images in the browser while giving printing. All my images sources are dynamic and coming from the service. I am just setting the url dynamically to the image source.**

```
<%_.each( Documents, function(oDocument) {%>
    <div class="images span1">          
        <img  src="<%- oDocument.URL%>" width="98" height="70" />       
    </div>
<% });%>
```

in print preview only one image is coming rest all coming as dots. if i cancel the print and give print again all are coming fine.

Thanks,
Jeevitha

Comment: It may be useful if you provide the respective source code.

Comment: Requesting the resources (ie. in an `<img src>` positioned so that it cannot be seen) will fetch the resource, and cache it if the browser feels like it. The IMG `onload` event can then be monitored to ensure the resource has been fetched, and presumably cached.

Comment: Do you still require assistance Jeevitha or has your problem now been solved?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I am still having a problem. I am using backbone.js and need to cache the images in the function where i am creating the model. I have provided more details in the question. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done purely in JavaScript by using the [Image object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image).

```
var cachedImage = new Image();
cachedImage.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert('Cached image loaded');            
});
cachedImage.src = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png';
```

I have created a working [JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/wc1zrL0v/) showing this at http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/wc1zrL0v/

The new images could be created in response to a user event, for example clicking on a button, or even scrolling past a certain position. If the image from the server has the proper cache headers, it will then be retained in the browser cache for later use in your print page.

You will be able to see the request in the "Network" tab of the Chrome dev tools, or by using the excellent [Fiddler tool from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Successful load will also trigger the load event listener added in the code sample.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to implement the following in my function where i am creating view model.                                       var cachedImage = new Image();
cachedImage.addEventListener('load', function () {
            });
            cachedImage.src = 'http://localhost:60883/Information/Document/1411432';

            var PrintModal = new Backbone.Model({
                Number: app.activeJob.get('Number'),
                ID: app.activeJob.get('ID'),
                HeaderLabel: titleString,
            });
            PrintModal.set('Documents', arrDocuments);

Comment: But still not working. i cant use windows onload because all the images i am trying to load are dynamic and coming from the service.

Comment: This is partially working for me. I need to wait to load all my images to be loaded in the cache. currently, the next line is getting executed even before downloading the image

Comment: This is the purpose of the load event listener on the image. The script will continue immediately to the next line, so you will need to use one or more callback functions to trigger the desired action(s) after the image(s) have successfully loaded. You should also make sure you are handling a fail case, where the URL is wrong, server is down,  or network conditions prevent successful download.

Comment: @user3527063 To be absolutely clear - you are listening for the load event on the image object, and not the window which may well already have fired.

Comment: Thank you.. i have done the following steps and worked fine. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

**I have called the custom function with the array of images i want to cache. Used Jquery 'Deffered' to hold the next operation until all the images are loaded. This is working very fine**

```
var $deferredimages = $.Deferred();
var items = []; // load all the images paths

            PreloadImages(items, loadImageitem, function (){                
                 $deferredimages.resolve();
            })


function PreloadImages(items, preloadimages, allDone) {

    var count = items.length;

    // this callback counts down the things to do.
    var pendingimages = function (items, i) {
        count--;
        if (0 == count) {
            allDone(items);
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        // 'do' each thing, and await callback.
        preloadimages(items, i, pendingimages);
    }
}

function loadImageitem(items, i, onComplete) {
    var onLoad = function (e) {
        e.target.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);

        // this next line can be removed.
        // only here to prove the image was loaded.
        document.body.appendChild(e.target);

        // notify that we're done.
        onComplete(items, i);
    }
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
    img.src = items[i];
    img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Reference http://jsfiddle.net/8baGb/1/